# REGEX Pattern to parse data in parenthesis and semicolon delineated

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to parse this text:

```
HTop 1.1 (iPhone; iPhone OS 4.3.3)
```

The data I am trying to specifically extract are:

- 1.1
- iPhone
- iPhone OS 4.3.3

I can get most of the data, however the "(" keep coming into my regex results.  Cant really understand why, and was hoping someone with more knowledge could help?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a regular expression like this one:

```
^HTop (\d+\.\d+) \((.*); (.*)\)$
```

Note that the inner brackets are excaped (`\(` and `\)`) such that they match literally and are not included in the groups.

Comment: A very good!  Thank you.  If there is however a third semicolon item, this breaks, is there an easy fix to account for either 2 or 3 items separated by the semicolon?

Comment: You may use `^HTop (\d+\.\d+) \(([^;]*); ([^;]*)(?:; ([^;]*))?\)$`